# (terraform) create two gcp instances with static ips

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I want launch two instances by terraform in gcp with static ips. I can reserved static ips. And create vm without static ips. But I can merge this is two apportunitu
below my terraform code

```
data "google_compute_default_service_account" "default" {
  project = var.project_id
}

# reserved statuc ips
resource "google_compute_address" "static" {
  count = length(var.ext_ip_name)
  project      = var.project_id
  name  = var.ext_ip_name[count.index] # ["ip1", "ip2"]
  region = var.region
  address_type = "EXTERNAL"
}

# create vm
resource "google_compute_instance" "vm" {
  for_each = var.virtual_machines
  name         = each.key
  machine_type = each.value.vm_size
  zone         = each.value.zone
  project = var.project_id
  tags = ["foo", "bar"]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-11"
      size  = 100
      type  = "pd-standard"
      labels = {
        my_label = "value"
      }
    }
  }


  network_interface {
    network = var.network
    subnetwork = "k8s-general-prod-gke-subnet"
    subnetwork_project = var.project_id
    access_config {
# !!! there is need insert static ip from  google_compute_address.static !!!
#        nat_ip       = google_compute_address.static[count.index].address
#        network_tier = "PREMIUM"
      }

  }

  metadata = {
    foo = "bar"
  }


    service_account {
      email  = data.google_compute_default_service_account.default.email
      scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
    }
}
```

when I uncommented

```
#        nat_ip       = google_compute_address.static[count.index].address
#        network_tier = "PREMIUM"
```

I got error

```
│ Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context
│ 
│   on instances.tf line 40, in resource "google_compute_instance" "vm":
│   40:         nat_ip       = google_compute_address.static[count.index].address
│ 
│ The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data"
│ blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.
```

I expected two vm with static ips.

Comment: You cannot mix resources created with `count` and `for_each`. It may be a better idea to use the same variable with `for_each` in both resources.

Comment: Thnx, I did it.  Now all OK.

```
resource "google_compute_address" "static" {
    for_each = var.virtual_machines
   name  = each.key
```
```
        nat_ip       = google_compute_address.static[each.key].address
```